# Background Colour width when hovering over text

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty stuck right now, I'm working on a site and I have the height of the list on my navigation bar sorted but now I want to make the width bigger so when I hover on it the background colour covers a slightly bigger area instead of brushing up against the end of the text.

I've tried padding it but all that seems to do is move the text over slightly and then center the text within that area.

Image (Don't have enough reputation to embed): https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GoIf.png

This is the CSS I currently have for it. I would appreciate any help with this!

```css
html {
 margin: 0;
}
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}
.navigation {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: lighter;
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
 width: 100%;
 height: 72px;
 background-image: url("images/download.png");
}
.navigation ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation li {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 25px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 120px;
}
.navigation li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
 height: 100%;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;

 width: 80px;
 background-color: #556;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
 </head>


 <body>
  <div class="navigation">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the HTML Markup too

Comment: Edited, HTML Markup added.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for.

[Solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYMyNw)

We remove the width from the parent and make the links `block` elements with `padding`

```
.navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 120px;
}

.navigation li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 26px 30px;
}

.navigation li a:hover {
  background-color: #556;
}
```

And making the li float `right` will mess up the order of your links consider floating the parent `ul` insted.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to apply the hover state to the `li` instead of the `a`, here's my suggestion:

```css
html {
 margin: 0;
}
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}
.navigation {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: lighter;
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
 width: 100%;
 height: 72px;
 background-image: url("images/download.png");
}
.navigation ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation li {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 25px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 25px;
        margin-right: 95px;
}
.navigation li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
.navigation li:hover {
 height: 100%;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;

 width: 80px;
 background-color: #556;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
 </head>


 <body>
  <div class="navigation">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mj8Lh31x/

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
.navigation {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("images/download.png");
}
.navigation ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation li {
  padding: 30px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation li a {
  padding: 30px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
  background-color: #556;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```